import data to Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server
I have deployed my django app to azure ans use Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server. I have my postgresql database in local, how can i import data from my local server to Azure.
enter image description here
I can't access Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server by pgAdmin because default Connectivity method in Azure is Private access (VNet Integration) and i can't change it

With  private access, no public endpoint is available, and only hosts located on the same network can access Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server. Therefore, you should enable public access to the database while creating the server as shown below. However, according to  this, it is not possible to change the networking option once the server is created. Create new server with below configuration:

Add the client IP address by creating a firewall rule as shown below:

You will then be able to connect to the database through the pgAdmin successfully, as shown below:

